# How to pre-populate custom field in signup form for secure zone in Adobe Business Catalyst?

Tags: forms, field, registration, business-catalyst

I have created a signup form for secure zone in Business Catalyst. I want to give user access to that form in order to update the fields. I have created the page and its working only problem is there is no way to pre-populate custom fields in the form. I talked to their support and research a lot but all in vain. This is very basic thing BC missing. Is there a hack for it or some alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Good News** Now Business Catalyst supports this feature for more information read:
[Allowing Customers to view and update CRM details](http://kb.worldsecuresystems.com/460/bc_460.html?bc-partner)

Comment: For the list of the specific tags to use to pre-fill data (such as `{module_fullname}` and `{module_emailaddress}`, refer to this page: https://forums.adobe.com/docs/DOC-2363#jive_content_id_Prepopulate_web_form_fields

Answer (score 2):

Just adding for anyone finding this that you can also populate fields that have been created and extended in the crm if they're stored against the customer record.

```
{module_customerfield,crmextformID,FieldID}
```

eg

```
{module_customerfield,7470,82256}
```

More info in the [forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/980966).

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same issue and hopefully there will be someway they can fix this in the future. What I did for the time being is I used other tags that I was not using. IE module_workcity was not and won't be used by me so I then put that in a field that I needed the custom tag for. Here is a screen shot of what I am referring to. - http://screencast.com/t/b3pvuOcTi one thing to note here the screen name is different than username for this site.

Note: When the user signs up I have the person filling out a field for the "workcity" and just change the labeling.

Not sure if this is an option for you, and it can take some work but might help.

Hope this helps. - Another note BC related question you will get quicker answers on the forums there - http://businesscatalyst.com/support/forums

Comment: One note: The BC Wishlist has items that are similar to what you ask. Go vote on the items you see there: http://businesscatalyst.com/wish-list/list-public

Comment: A follow up here: This issue is now fixed and you can pre-populate custom fields.